# Is there a way to attach a custom validation message when extending the validator in laravel?

Tags: laravel, validation, laravel-5, laravel-validation

Currently I have implemented following custom validation, but I don't know how to attach a custom message if the validation fails. To clarify, I need to define the error message when extending validator

```
Validator::extend('phone_number', function($attribute, $value, $parameters)
    {
       // is there anyway I could define a error message here, if this validation fails,
        if (strlen($value) === 9)
        {
            if (substr($value, 0, 1) === '0')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (substr($value, 0, 1) != '0')
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        return true;
    });
```

I have currently placed this code within boot method, and in documentation they say there's a way to define custom message as follows, but I really don't understand it.

```
public function boot()
{

Validator::extend(...);

Validator::replacer('foo', function ($message, $attribute, $rule, $parameters) {
    return str_replace(...);
});
```

}

Comment: You can simply add a third arg to extend `Validator::extend('phone_number', function($attribute, $value, $parameters){//....}, 'You custom message');` ;)

Comment: is that what your looking for ?

Comment: Yes, this is it, Could you post this as an answer? And thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can specify your message by adding a third parameter to the `extend` method like this :

```
Validator::extend('phone_number', function($attribute, $value, $parameters) {

    if (strlen($value) === 9)
    {
        if (substr($value, 0, 1) === '0')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        if (substr($value, 0, 1) != '0')
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}, 'Your custom message goes here'); // <--- HERE
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put your custom validation rule messages in `resources/lang/en/validation.php`.

Also have a look at this page: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-5-custom-validator-rules

It is a nicer way to create your custom validation rules.

Comment: Yes, I do know about this method, but right now  I can't use this, so looking for an alternative.